# inets httpd: Can't get simple esi script to work

Tags: erlang, inets

Here's the proplist_file that I use to configure the httpd server:

```
[
  {modules, [
    mod_alias,
    mod_actions,
    mod_cgi,
    mod_get,
    mod_esi,
    mod_log
  ]},
  {bind_address, "localhost"}, 
  {port,0},
  {server_name,"httpd_test"},
  {server_root,"/Users/7stud/erlang_programs/inets_proj"},
  {document_root,"./htdocs"},
  {script_alias, {"/cgi-bin/", "/Users/7stud/erlang_programs/inets_proj/cgi-bin/"} },
  {erl_script_alias, {"/cgi-bin/example", [httpd_example]} },
  {erl_script_nocache, true},
  {error_log, "./errors.log"},
  {transfer_log, "./requests.log"}
].
```

For esi scripts the key property is:

```
  {erl_script_alias, {"/cgi-bin/example", [httpd_example]} }
```

According to the [inets docs](http://erlang.org/doc/apps/inets/inets.pdf):

> **ESI Properties - Requires mod_esi**
>
> **{erl_script_alias, {URLPath, [AllowedModule]}}**
>   URLPath = string() and AllowedModule = atom(). erl_script_alias marks all URLs
>   matching url-path as erl scheme scripts. A matching URL is mapped into
>   a specific module and function, for example:
>
> ```
>  {erl_script_alias, {"/cgi-bin/example", [httpd_example]}}
> ```
>
> A request to
>   `http://your.server.org/cgi-bin/example/httpd_example:yahoo` would refer
>   to `httpd_example:yahoo/3` or, if that does not exist,
>   httpd_example:yahoo/2 and
>   `http://your.server.org/cgi-bin/example/other:yahoo` would not be
>   allowed to execute.

My directory structure is:

```
~/erlang_programs$ tree inets_proj/
inets_proj/
├── cgi-bin
│   ├── 1.pl
│   ├── example
│   │   ├── httpd_example.beam
│   │   └── httpd_example.erl
│   ├── httpd_example.beam
│   └── httpd_example.erl
├── cl.beam
├── cl.erl
├── errors.log
├── htdocs
│   └── file1.txt
├── httpd_example.beam
├── httpd_example.erl
├── mylog.log
├── requests.log
├── s.beam
├── s.erl
└── server.conf
```

I wasn't sure where to put the `httpd_example` module, so I put it in several places.

esi_mod.erl:

```
-module(esi_mod).
-compile(export_all).

log(Data) ->
    {ok, IoDevice} = file:open(
        "/Users/7stud/erlang_programs/inets_proj/mylog.log",
        [append]
    ),

    ok = file:write(IoDevice, Data),
    file:close(IoDevice).

get_data(SessionID, _Env, _Input) ->
    Headers = "Content-Type: text/html\r\n\r\n",
    Data = "Hello, esi",

    log(["--Inside esi_mod:get_data() ~n"]),

    ok = mod_esi:deliver(SessionID, Headers),  %Headers must be a string.
    ok = mod_esi:deliver(SessionID, Data).     %Data can be an iolist.
```

Here is the server info as reported in the shell:

```
$ erl
Erlang/OTP 20 [erts-9.2] [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [ds:4:4:10] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]
Eshell V9.2  (abort with ^G)

1> c(s).         
s.erl:2: Warning: export_all flag enabled - all functions will be exported
{ok,s}
2> S = s:start().
<0.86.0>
3> httpd:info(S).
[{mime_types,[{"htm","text/html"},{"html","text/html"}]},
 {server_name,"httpd_test"},
 {erl_script_nocache,true},
 {script_alias,{"/cgi-bin/",
                "/Users/7stud/erlang_programs/inets_proj/cgi-bin/"}},
 {bind_address,{127,0,0,1}},
 {modules,[mod_alias,mod_actions,mod_cgi,mod_get,mod_esi,
           mod_log]},
 {server_root,"/Users/7stud/erlang_programs/inets_proj"},
 {erl_script_alias,{"/cgi-bin/example",[httpd_example]}},
 {port,64470},
 {transfer_log,<0.93.0>},
 {error_log,<0.92.0>},
 {document_root,"./htdocs"}]
4>
```

Here's my request:

```
~$ curl -vv "http://localhost:64470/cgi-bin/example/httpd_example:get_data"
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 64470 (#0)
> GET /cgi-bin/example/httpd_example:get_data HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:64470
> User-Agent: curl/7.58.0
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 404 Object Not Found
< Date: Wed, 28 Feb 2018 10:22:38 GMT
< Server: inets/6.4.5
< Content-Type: text/html
< Content-Length: 245
< 
<HTML>
       <HEAD>
           <TITLE>Object Not Found</TITLE>
      </HEAD>
      <BODY>
      <H1>Object Not Found</H1>
The requested URL &#47;cgi-bin&#47;example&#47;httpd_example:get_data was not found on this server.
</BODY>
      </HTML>
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
~$
```

errors.log:

> [Timestamp] access to
>   /cgi-bin/example/httpd_example:get_data failed for 127.0.0.1, reason: 
>   "httpd_file: Can't open
>   ./htdocs/cgi-bin/example/httpd_example:get_data: File not found"

According to the error message, the request path:

```
/cgi-bin/example/httpd_example:get_data
```

got converted to:

```
./htdocs/cgi-bin/example/httpd_example:get_data
```

which means the request path was tacked onto `./htdocs`.  Huh??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, I got things working. First, while I was searching around I happened across:

[10 Essential Erlang Tools for Erlang Developers](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/erlang/10-essential-erlang-tools-for-erlang-developers#BtCAVQHe4qv0Rk3M.99)

and therein lies the single greatest erlang "tool" that I've used to date:

> Command history that isn't wiped out when you exit the erlang shell.

You can install/enable it by following the instructions here:  https://github.com/ferd/erlang-history

Back to the problem at hand:

1) I found that the order of the httpd modules is important.  `mod_esi` needs to be before `mod_get`:

server.conf:

```
[
  {modules, [
    mod_alias,
    mod_actions,
    mod_esi,
    mod_cgi,
    mod_get,
    mod_log
  ]},
  {bind_address, "localhost"}, 
  {port,0},
  {server_name,"httpd_test"},
  {server_root,"/Users/7stud/erlang_programs/inets_proj"},
  {document_root,"./htdocs"},
  {script_alias, {"/cgi-bin/", "/Users/7stud/erlang_programs/inets_proj/cgi-bin/"} },
  {erl_script_alias, {"/erl", [mymod]} },
  {erl_script_nocache, true},
  {error_log, "./errors.log"},
  {transfer_log, "./requests.log"}
].
```

After getting the module order correct, I stopped getting the "File not found" errors due to the strange converted paths.

2) The code for the esi module has to be in the `server_root` directory. My esi module's name is `mymod.erl`:

```
~/erlang_programs$ tree inets_proj/
inets_proj/
├── cgi-bin
│   ├── 1.pl
│   ├── example
│   │   ├── httpd_example.beam
│   │   └── httpd_example.erl
│   ├── httpd_example.beam
│   └── httpd_example.erl
├── cl.beam
├── cl.erl
├── errors.log
├── htdocs
│   └── file1.txt
├── mylog.log
├── mymod.beam
├── mymod.erl
├── requests.log
├── s.beam
├── s.erl
├── server.conf
├── xhttpd_example.beam
└── xhttpd_example.erl
```

3) Because I specified:

```
{erl_script_alias, {"/erl", [mymod]} }
```

the url I need to use is:

```
http://localhost:57867/erl/mymod:get_data
```

The port has to match the server's port.  The proper path is whatever path you specify in the erl_script_alias property plus `/modulename:funcname` or `/modulename/funcname`.

Here's mymod.erl:

```
-module(mymod).
-export([get_data/3]).

log(Data) ->
    {ok, IoDevice} = file:open(
        "/Users/7stud/erlang_programs/inets_proj/mylog.log",
        [append]
    ),

    file:write(IoDevice, Data),
    file:close(IoDevice).

get_data(SessionID, Env, Input) ->
    Headers = "Content-Type: text/html\r\n\r\n",
    Data = [
        <<"Hello, ">>, 
        "esi!\n"
    ],

    log(io_lib:format(
        "Inside mymod:get_data()\nSessionId=~p\nEnv=~p\nInput=~p\n", 
        [SessionID, Env, Input]
    )),

    mod_esi:deliver(SessionID, Headers),  %Headers must be a string.
    mod_esi:deliver(SessionID, Data).     %Data can be an iolist.
```

According to the [mod_esi docs](http://erlang.org/doc/man/mod_esi.html):

> **mod_esi:deliver/2** shall be used to generate the response to the client and SessionID is an identifier that shall by used when calling
>   this function, do not assume anything about the datatype. This
>   function may be called several times to chunk the response data.
>   Notice that the first chunk of data sent to the client must at least
>   contain all HTTP header fields that the response will generate. If the
>   first chunk does not contain the end of HTTP header, that is,
>   "\r\n\r\n", the server assumes that no HTTP header fields will be
>   generated.

4)  Compile mymod.erl:

```
~/erlang_programs/inets_proj$ erlc mymod.erl 
~/erlang_programs/inets_proj$
```

You have to recompile after every change you make to mymod.erl, then restart the server.  It would be simpler if this would work:

```
5> httpd:reload_config("server.conf", disturbing).
{error,{missing_property,server_name}}
```

but even though my config file does specify a server_name property I get that error.

5) I suggest you do error logging by including `mod_log` in the list of modules and specifying the property:

```
{error_log, "./errors.log"}
```

Then check that file for any feedback on what happened when a request fails.

6) When I called my custom log() method (in order to write some info to a file) unbeknownst to me the log() method was causing an exception, which caused the server to reject the request and enter a `module traverse failed` message in error.log:

```
[Timestamp], module traverse failed: mod_esi:do => 
   Error Type:  exit
   Error:       {mod_esi_linked_process_died,<0.97.0>,normal}
   Stack trace: [{mod_esi,receive_headers,1,[{file,"mod_esi.erl"},{line,428}]},
                 {mod_esi,deliver_webpage_chunk,3,
                     [{file,"mod_esi.erl"},{line,389}]},
                 {mod_esi,erl_scheme_webpage_chunk,5,
                     [{file,"mod_esi.erl"},{line,380}]},
                 {mod_esi,generate_webpage,7,
                     [{file,"mod_esi.erl"},{line,314}]},
                 {httpd_response,traverse_modules,2,
                     [{file,"httpd_response.erl"},{line,77}]},
                 {httpd_response,generate_and_send_response,1,
                     [{file,"httpd_response.erl"},{line,44}]},
                 {httpd_request_handler,handle_response,1,
                     [{file,"httpd_request_handler.erl"},{line,655}]},
                 {gen_server,try_dispatch,4,
                     [{file,"gen_server.erl"},{line,616}]}]
```

7) Here's the module I used to start the server:

```
-module(s).
-compile(export_all).

%Need to look up port with httpd:info(Server)

ensure_inets_start() ->
    case inets:start() of
        ok -> ok;
        {error,{already_started,inets}} -> ok
    end.


start() ->
    ok = s:ensure_inets_start(),

    {ok, Server} = inets:start(httpd, 
        [{proplist_file, "./server.conf"}]
    ),
    Server.


stop(Server) ->
    ok = inets:stop(httpd, Server).
```

8) Here are a few sample requests using curl...

Server info in the shell:

```
~/erlang_programs/inets_proj$ erl
Erlang/OTP 20 [erts-9.2] [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [ds:4:4:10] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]

Eshell V9.2  (abort with ^G)
1> c(s).         
s.erl:2: Warning: export_all flag enabled - all functions will be exported
{ok,s}
2> S = s:start().
<0.86.0>
3> httpd:info(S).
[{mime_types,[{"htm","text/html"},{"html","text/html"}]},
 {server_name,"httpd_test"},
 {erl_script_nocache,true},
 {script_alias,{"/cgi-bin/",
                "/Users/7stud/erlang_programs/inets_proj/cgi-bin/"}},
 {bind_address,{127,0,0,1}},
 {modules,[mod_alias,mod_actions,mod_esi,mod_cgi,mod_get,
           mod_log]},
 {server_root,"/Users/7stud/erlang_programs/inets_proj"},
 {erl_script_alias,{"/erl",[mymod]}},
 {port,59202},
 {transfer_log,<0.93.0>},
 {error_log,<0.92.0>},
 {document_root,"./htdocs"}]
4>
```

Request 1 (esi get request):

```
~$  curl -v "http://localhost:57867/erl/mymod:get_data"
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 57867 (#0)
> GET /erl/mymod:get_data HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:57867
> User-Agent: curl/7.58.0
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Wed, 28 Feb 2018 13:28:09 GMT
< Server: inets/6.4.5
< Cache-Control: no-cache
< Pragma: no-cache
< Expires: Wed, 28 Feb 2018 13:28:09 GMT
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Content-Type: text/html
< 
Hello, esi!
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
~$
```

mylog.log:

```
~/erlang_programs/inets_proj$ cat mylog.log
...
...
Inside mymod:get_data()
SessionId=<0.99.0>
Env=[{server_software,"inets/6.4.5"},
     {server_name,"httpd_test"},
     {host_name,"ChristophersMBP"},
     {gateway_interface,"CGI/1.1"},
     {server_protocol,"HTTP/1.1"},
     {server_port,59202},
     {request_method,"GET"},
     {remote_addr,"127.0.0.1"},
     {peer_cert,undefined},
     {script_name,"/erl/mymod:get_data"},
     {http_host,"localhost:59202"},
     {http_user_agent,"curl/7.58.0"},
     {http_accept,"*/*"}]
Input=[]
-------
```

Request 2 (esi get request with query string):

```
~$  curl -v "http://localhost:59202/erl/mymod:get_data?a=1&b=2"
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 59202 (#0)
> GET /erl/mymod:get_data?a=1&b=2 HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:59202
> User-Agent: curl/7.58.0
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Wed, 28 Feb 2018 13:47:41 GMT
< Server: inets/6.4.5
< Cache-Control: no-cache
< Pragma: no-cache
< Expires: Wed, 28 Feb 2018 13:47:41 GMT
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Content-Type: text/html
< 
Hello, esi!
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```

mylog.log:

```
~/erlang_programs/inets_proj$ cat mylog.log
...
...
Inside mymod:get_data()
SessionId=<0.105.0>
Env=[{server_software,"inets/6.4.5"},
     {server_name,"httpd_test"},
     {host_name,"ChristophersMBP"},
     {gateway_interface,"CGI/1.1"},
     {server_protocol,"HTTP/1.1"},
     {server_port,59202},
     {request_method,"GET"},
     {remote_addr,"127.0.0.1"},
     {peer_cert,undefined},
     {script_name,"/erl/mymod:get_data?a=1&b=2"},
     {http_host,"localhost:59202"},
     {http_user_agent,"curl/7.58.0"},
     {http_accept,"*/*"},
     {query_string,"a=1&b=2"}]
Input="a=1&b=2"
```

Request 3 (esi post request):

```
~$  curl -v --data "a=1&b=2" "http://localhost:59202/erl/mymod:get_data"
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 59202 (#0)
> POST /erl/mymod:get_data HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:59202
> User-Agent: curl/7.58.0
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 7
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
> 
* upload completely sent off: 7 out of 7 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Wed, 28 Feb 2018 13:51:44 GMT
< Server: inets/6.4.5
< Cache-Control: no-cache
< Pragma: no-cache
< Expires: Wed, 28 Feb 2018 13:51:44 GMT
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Content-Type: text/html
< 
Hello, esi!
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```

mylog.log:

```
Inside mymod:get_data()
SessionId=<0.108.0>
Env=[{server_software,"inets/6.4.5"},
     {server_name,"httpd_test"},
     {host_name,"ChristophersMBP"},
     {gateway_interface,"CGI/1.1"},
     {server_protocol,"HTTP/1.1"},
     {server_port,59202},
     {request_method,"POST"},
     {remote_addr,"127.0.0.1"},
     {peer_cert,undefined},
     {script_name,"/erl/mymod:get_data"},
     {http_host,"localhost:59202"},
     {http_user_agent,"curl/7.58.0"},
     {http_accept,"*/*"},
     {http_content_length,"7"},
     {http_content_type,"application/x-www-form-urlencoded"}]
Input="a=1&b=2"
-------
```

Request 4 (cgi get request):

```
~$  curl -v "http://localhost:59202/cgi-bin/1.pl"
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 59202 (#0)
> GET /cgi-bin/1.pl HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:59202
> User-Agent: curl/7.58.0
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Wed, 28 Feb 2018 13:41:43 GMT
< Server: inets/6.4.5
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Content-Type: text/html
< 
Hello, Perl.
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```

Request 5 (get request for regular file from document_root directory):

```
~$  curl -v "http://localhost:59202/file1.txt"
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 59202 (#0)
> GET /file1.txt HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:59202
> User-Agent: curl/7.58.0
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Date: Wed, 28 Feb 2018 13:42:15 GMT
< Server: inets/6.4.5
< Content-Type: text/plain
< Etag: nCZT0114
< Content-Length: 14
< Last-Modified: Mon, 26 Feb 2018 02:51:52 GMT
< 
Hello, world!
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
```